# How to import two classes with the same name in different packages?

Tags: java, import, name-collision

I want to import these two classes, both named `Query` - one a **JDO** class, the other a **JPA** class, to use in different methods in the same class.

```
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.persistence.Query;
```

Is there a way to globally import both of them at the same time at the top of the file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm afraid, no. But you don't have to import class to use it: just reference one of the classes by its full name, like

```
javax.jdo.Query query = getJDOQuery();
query.doSomething();
```

Then you can import another without name collisions.

BTW, sometimes if you start getting lots of such name such collisions in your class, it's a subtle hint for refactoring: splitting functionality of one big class between several small ones.

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers are correct. I'd like to show you how class name conflicts can be handled in Kotlin ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports)).

If there is a name clash, we can disambiguate by using `as` keyword to locally rename the clashing entity:

```
import javax.jdo.Query // Query is accessible
import javax.persistence.Query as jpaQuery // jpaQuery stands for 'javax.persistence.Query'
```

That's +1 reason why you should consider [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) for your next project.

Answer (score 2):

The only purpose of an `import` statement is to establish a shorthand alias for a fully-qualified name. If you were allowed to imported both, you'd create an ambiguity that would require type inference to resolve, and make your code extremely difficult to read.

Comment: @Ment - well, the Java language does not allow that, and it doesn't support the equivalent of `typedef` either.

Comment: Sure, that would be cool, but it doesn't work that way (yet).