# When importing two classes with the same unqualified name, which will be chosen?

Tags: java, import

When we import `List` from both `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`, which one is selected when we refer to `List` in subsequent code?

Comment: best way to find is implement and test. :)

Comment: `java.util.List` as `java.lang.List` doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no `java.lang.List`.

Comment: if you import both, the compiler will complain about an ambiguous type. you'll need to specify it yourself, like:  java.lang.List a = new java.lang.List();
but I assume you just meant this as an example, since the java.lang.List interface doesn't exist.

Comment: This has potential to be a good question if it's reworded, please don't close it just yet.

Comment: `java.awt.List` and `java.util.List`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing two classes with same name. How to handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079823/importing-two-classes-with-same-name-how-to-handle)

Comment: Also see: [How to import two classes with the same name in different packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731125/how-to-import-two-classes-with-the-same-name-in-different-packages)

Comment: Asking of a construct not exists. You simply *cannot* import both.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. A compile-time error similar to the following will occur:

`The import java.awt.List collides with another import statement`

The way to achieve this is to qualify one of the references.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Example
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<>();
        java.awt.List guiList = new java.awt.List();
}
```